# Hi, yum/dnf command gives an output "no match for argument : htop, inotify-tools" or any packages for that matter - please suggest

Tags: linux, centos

last metadata expiration check: 0:11:28 ago on mon 20 feb 2023 11:08:18 AM EST.
No match for argument:htop
Error: Unable to find a match: htop

Comment: Can you tell us more about your version of CentOS? Is it 7 or 8? Is it installed on bare-metal or in a container or VM? Alternately, have you installed epel repo for additional packages, yet? (`sudo yum install epel-release`)

Comment: its CentOS 7 and installed on Oracle VM

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - Forever Cuber it worked after epel-release

Comment: Great! I am glad you have a resolution. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling to install third-party packages in CentOS 7,  you may need to enable the "Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux" (EPEL) repository.

https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/install-epel-linux

You can do this in a terminal by giving the command:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

and then installing htop:

```
sudo yum install htop
```